# How do I completely get rid of dphys-swapfile on buster 64-bit?

Tags: pi-4, swap-space

I created a new SD card image with Raspberry Pi OS Lite, Buster, 2023-05-03 and loaded it into my unit.  After configuring everything and rebooting, I see:

```
[Failed] Failed to start dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete the swap file.
```

I do not want to use swap, so I have tried all of the following to remove this:

```
systemctl stop dphys-swapfile.service
systemctl disable dphys-swapfile.service
update-rc.d dphys-swapfile disable
rm /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile
rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dphys-swapfile.service
apt-get uninstall dphys-swapfile
apt purge dphys-swapfile
sudo chmod -x /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile
```

I also edited `/boot/cmdline.txt` to add noswap.

Even after all of this, whenever I reboot the system it happens again and `/etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile` and `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dphys-swapfile.service` are reborn.  Does anyone know how to remove whatever is recreating this from startup?

Also, when I run `swapon` directly, it fails indicating an invalid argument.  The swap path exists at `/var/swap` on my disk with root as owner and 600 as mode.

Note that since it is never successfully run, then it is not actually active in the system, but what I do not want to see `degraded` every time I `systemctl status` due to a service unit that should not be there in the first place.

Comment: `systemctl mask dphys-swapfile` (documented in `man systemctl`)

Comment: @goldilocks - I have tried that too, but I still get a `degraded` state when I `systemctl status`.

Comment: interesting that  you run the last command using `sudo` but none of the others - do you get errors? running the first two using `sudo systemctl ...etc` would be enough to turn off swap immediately (first command) and disable it from running on boot (second command)

Comment: I think you might have a non-reproducible problem; I always disable this as I prefer a swap partition or not to bother with it at all.  I've been doing that pretty much since I started with Pis 10+ years ago (or the equivalent with zram swap, which used to be the default I think).  I checked a 4 and a 3B+ both running bullseye, 64-bit and 32-bit, one with a swap partition and the other with no swap, and `systemctl status dphys-swapfile` yields disabled + inactive/dead.

Comment: @goldilocks - I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 with 8 GB of RAM and Samsung Extreme external SSD in the system.  I basically create an image with the Raspberry Pi Imager with Buster Lite 64-bit, then proceed to the various steps noted here.  When I reboot, the system, `/etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile` and `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dphys-swapfile.service` reappear and when I `systemctl status` I see `degraded`.  Something in the system seems to be creating the service again at boot.

Comment: Side note:  My ultimate solution to the problem was to enter single user mode, copy the entire `/var` folder to a folder on the external SSD and mount it there.  In this case, I just leave `dphys-swapfile` running and given that I have 8 gigabytes of ram, I think that it probably is not doing much of anything.